Ensuring Dependencies are installed
I am a beginner programmer and I have always wondered how dependencies are installed for a project file. If I have a python file that requires a library to be run; how do I ensure that a person downloading and running the file has the dependency and can run it?
I know that you can just list the dependencies in a README file but how do I install the dependencies autmoatically?

Store dependencies in the requirements.txt. Then install them by using pip install -r requirements.txt

Other option is to use pyproject.toml (read documentation about it). You can install dependencies listed in the .toml file using python -m pip install .

You may also need to know about virtual environments, so you can install python modules within this folder only.


how do I ensure that a person downloading and running the file has the
dependency and can run it?

What you are describing is distribution. There are many tools for doing this, one of more popular is pyinstaller

PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into
a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing
a Python interpreter or any modules.

See answers to How can I distribute python programs? if you wish to entertain alternative ways of doing that.
